# openAL tutorial for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, openal

I need tools to learn how to use OpenAL in Mac OS X applications. I have done a decent amount of iOS and Mac development, and am usually good at learning new things quickly. could anyone supply a site or two that would have some tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

How about this one ? It seems the most highly ranked on Google. Its pretty easy to understand, and the entire tutorial is explained quite well.

http://www.edenwaith.com/products/pige/tutorials/openal.php